# Parsec - error "combinator 'many' is applied to a parser that accepts an empty string"

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm trying to write a parser using Parsec that will parse literate Haskell files, such as the following:

```
The classic 'Hello, world' program.

\begin{code}

main = putStrLn "Hello, world"

\end{code}

More text.
```

I've written the following, sort-of-inspired by the examples in RWH:

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

main
    = do contents <- readFile "hello.lhs"
         let results = parseLiterate contents
         print results

data Element
    = Text String
    | Haskell String
    deriving (Show)


parseLiterate :: String -> Either ParseError [Element]

parseLiterate input
    = parse literateFile "(unknown)" input



literateFile
    = many codeOrProse

codeOrProse
    = code <|> prose

code
    = do eol
         string "\\begin{code}"
         eol
         content <- many anyChar
         eol
         string "\\end{code}"
         eol
         return $ Haskell content

prose
    = do content <- many anyChar
         return $ Text content

eol
    =   try (string "\n\r")
    <|> try (string "\r\n")
    <|> string "\n"
    <|> string "\r"
    <?> "end of line"
```

Which I hoped would result in something along the lines of:

```
[Text "The classic 'Hello, world' program.", Haskell "main = putStrLn \"Hello, world\"", Text "More text."]
```

(allowing for whitespace etc).

This compiles fine, but when run, I get the error:

```
*** Exception: Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Prim.many: combinator 'many' is applied to a parser that accepts an empty string
```

Can anyone shed any light on this, and possibly help with a solution please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As sth pointed out `many anyChar` is the problem. But not just in `prose` but also in `code`. The problem with `code` is, that `content <- many anyChar` will consume everything: The newlines and the `\end{code}` tag.

So, you need to have some way to tell the prose and the code apart. An easy (but maybe too naive) way to do so, is to look for backslashes:

```
literateFile = many codeOrProse <* eof

code = do string "\\begin{code}"
          content <- many $ noneOf "\\"
          string "\\end{code}"
          return $ Haskell content

prose = do content <- many1 $ noneOf "\\"
           return $ Text content
```

Now, you don't completely have the desired result, because the `Haskell` part will also contain newlines, but you can filter these out quite easily (given a function `filterNewlines` you could say `` `content <- filterNewlines <$> (many $ noneOf "\\") ``).

**Edit**

Okay, I think I found a solution (requires the newest Parsec version, because of `lookAhead`):

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import Control.Applicative hiding (many, (<|>))

main
    = do contents <- readFile "hello.lhs"
         let results = parseLiterate contents
         print results

data Element
    = Text String
    | Haskell String
    deriving (Show)    

parseLiterate :: String -> Either ParseError [Element]

parseLiterate input
    = parse literateFile "" input

literateFile
    = many codeOrProse

codeOrProse = code <|> prose

code = do string "\\begin{code}\n"
          c <- untilP (string "\\end{code}\n")
          string "\\end{code}\n"
          return $ Haskell c

prose = do t <- untilP $ (string "\\begin{code}\n") <|> (eof >> return "")
           return $ Text t

untilP p = do s <- many $ noneOf "\n"
              newline
              s' <- try (lookAhead p >> return "") <|> untilP p
              return $ s ++ s'
```

`untilP p` parses a line, then checks if the beginning of the next line can be successfully parsed by `p`. If so, it returns the empty string, otherwise it goes on. The `lookAhead` is needed, because otherwise the begin\end-tags would be consumed and `code` couldn't recognize them.

I guess it could still be made more concise (i.e. not having to repeat `string "\\end{code}\n"` inside `code`).

Comment: The problem is that both code and prose can contain backslashes (code because of lambdas etc, and prose because it can contain TeX commands).

Comment: (The only distinguishing factor is that \begin{code} and \end{code} must be on newlines).

Comment: I see - didn't think it through... I guess you'll have to refactor your grammar somehow, so that it checks after every newline if the next part is a \begin{code} or \end{code} string. Unfortunately. I'm not that experienced with grammars.

Comment: Fantastic, thankyou! I knew about `try` but hadn't seen `lookAhead` before.

Comment: `untilP` doesn't allow the section to be empty (it must contain at least one newline between the begin and end).  Allowing for an empty section, isn't `untilP s` the same as `manyTill (manyTill anyChar newline) (try s)`, without the need to slurp up the terminator again?

Answer (score 7):

I haven't tested it, but:

- `many anyChar` can match an empty string
- Therefore `prose` can match an empty string
- Therefore `codeOrProse` can match an empty string
- Therefore `literateFile` can loop forever, matching infinitely many empty strings

Changing `prose` to match `many1` characters might fix this problem.

(I'm not very familiar with Parsec, but how will `prose` know *how many* characters it should match? It might consume the whole input, never giving the `code` parser a second chance to look for the start of a new code segment. Alternatively it might only match one character in each call, making the `many`/`many1` in it useless.)

Comment: I definately see what you're saying, which is why I attempted to put the code part before the prose part in the <|>. I guess I want a non-greedy 'many'.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, here's another version I came up with (slightly expanded to handle other cases):

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

main
    = do contents <- readFile "test.tex"
         let results = parseLiterate contents
         print results

data Element
    = Text String
    | Haskell String
    | Section String
    deriving (Show)

parseLiterate :: String -> Either ParseError [Element]

parseLiterate input
    = parse literateFile "(unknown)" input

literateFile
    = do es <- many elements
         eof
         return es

elements
    = try section
  <|> try quotedBackslash
  <|> try code
  <|> prose

code
    = do string "\\begin{code}"
         c <- anyChar `manyTill` try (string "\\end{code}")
         return $ Haskell c

quotedBackslash
    = do string "\\\\"
         return $ Text "\\\\"

prose
    = do t <- many1 (noneOf "\\")
         return $ Text t

section
    = do string "\\section{"
         content <- many1 (noneOf "}")
         char '}'
         return $ Section content
```